# Set Azure App Service environment variables with microsoft devops deploy task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

For years we stored our environment variables in devops pipelines (for each environment) and had a custom powershell script for updating them on deploy.

[image]

recently on another project with similar need, I discovered that the task `Àzure App Service Deploy` had an `app settings` section, great. seems to be exactly what is needed to **get rid** of our powershell custom script.

however I didn't found (official documentation of the task doesn't mention it) how to re-use pipeline variables into task `app settings`. any idea if it's possible ?

[image]

Comment: Refer to the variables the same way you do in every other context: `$(VariableName)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the pipeline `Variables` you have to set your [variables](http://Application%20and%20Configuration%20Settings). Variables tab will look like:
[image: Variables tab]

Once the variables are set you can use them at your release pipeline under `Deploy Azure App Service` task in format `-key value`. As per documentation:

> Edit web app Application settings using the syntax -key value. Values containing spaces must be enclosed in double quotes. Examples: -Port 5000 -RequestTimeout 5000 and -WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE "Eastern Standard Time".

As you have values set the format will be `-key $(VariableName)`. This format should be familiar as pipelines refer to release [default variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables).

So your `App settings` at `Deploy Azure App Service` task will look like

`-Key1 $(Variable1) -Key2 $(Variable2)`

or:

[image]

To reuse same variables over the pipelines you can setup [Variable Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).